# Get the list of all the Youtube Channels that I am subscribed to

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to get a list of all the 800+ youtube channels that I am subscribed to.
It would be great if someone could provide a python sample for the same.

Yet to try the sample programs. But did have a look at youtube api.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Subscriptions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%22%5D%2C%22mine%22%3Atrue%7D) endpoint. As it requires obtaining authorization credentials, have a look to [this guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application). If you want to proceed using OAuth 2, here is the Python code suggested by the API itself:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Sample Python code for youtube.subscriptions.list
# See instructions for running these code samples locally:
# https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/code-samples#python

import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.subscriptions().list(
        part="snippet,contentDetails",
        mine=True
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Otherwise if you just want to proceed with an API key, you can proceed [this way](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%22%5D%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22CHANNEL_ID%22%7D) with this Python code requiring the channel id you are retrieving subscriptions for:

```py
import googleapiclient.discovery

youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    "youtube", "v3", developerKey="AIzaSy...")

request = youtube.subscriptions().list(
    part="snippet,contentDetails",
    channelId="CHANNEL_ID"
)
response = request.execute()

print(response)
```

Comment: thanks for the comment benjamin. I tried your api key sample code , but it isn't giving me a list of channels i'm subscribed too. For eg , if i was subscribed to : mkbhd , veritasium , it should display the names of the channels in a list. could you edit the sample program (api key version) to get that kind of output.